# How can I make my HTML page Flexible/Responsive for iPhone 6s

Tags: html, css

i so have made my HTML page with CSS, and everything looks fine on the PC! But on my iPhone 6S i have some problems with the view :( i have tried to make the page flexible with CSS, but no results.. can someone help me please?

I tried this:

```
@media (max-width:1024px) {

.ImageBig {

    max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}



.OpenContainer {
   width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
   background-color:white;

}


.ImageContainer {
    max-width: 100%;
height:auto;
 margin: 0 auto; 
top: 76%;
display: block;
position:absolute;


}


.ImageInfo {

    background-color:#bfc0c4;
    padding:10px;
    float: none;
  display: block;


}

.ImageBuy {
    background-color:#e5e8ed;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.exit {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    color:black;
}



}
```

But it still not showing good..
I want that it will show like this: [image: This is how it must be]

You can see the whole HTML page with CSS here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hntbojao/1/

--

I will really appreciate it if someone can help me out with this!

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would recommend placing the social buttons in the same div as the cart for starters

Comment: @Aziz Hi Aziz, yes that will be also good.. But for now the problem is the view on iphone 6 is like this: http://i.imgur.com/wRGi0Xm.png Its not showing good, so i want to make the page flexible

Comment: you see one of the problems here is that the image is too wide for `height: auto` to be useful, you'll need another approach, maybe give the image a specific height and apply `width: auto` and have its container hide the overflow

Comment: TBH unexpected request, maybe we can chat about it?

Comment: Ok please, can you start a chat? Because i dont know how i can do that

Comment: Why is hiring a professional web developer something nobody even considers anymore? They don't try to fix the brakes on their cars by themselves, but everyone's building their own website. And than they blame the framework, the host or anything else they can thing of... the site is not looking or behaving professionally.

Comment: I am overly booked, but I recommend you hire someone with a decent portfolio from your own country (or even your own area). Being familiar with how the target audience thinks and feels is a great asset when you build a website.

Comment: What is the purpose of your website? How is the content of the website going to be generated and structured? What's the average age of your target audience? Is your website going to be accessed more from mobile devices or from desktops? Are you going to change it completely in a few years or just add pages and develop new features gradually? Answering questions like these will get you closer to picking a framework (or, if that's the case) a static html template. Than you'll be able to discuss price and deadlines with a developer.

Comment: Seems like this question is too broad and would involve someone doing your work for you. If you want to learn, I'd suggest starting with learning how media queries work. If not, then look to hire someone, but I don't think this is the place for that...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I just want 1 thing, that the page will be responsive / flexible on iPhone 6s!

Comment: Ok, I'll get it done. I'll post it here when I'm done. Is there any library you're already loading in your project?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Really? Thanks men! I really appreciate that! If you want i can show you some things with TeamViewer.. Can we talk on chat?

Comment: I'm not fully aware if we're breaking or not some SO policy, but you can use my website's contact form to reach me and I'll respond.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks i just sent you a message ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is. Please note I adjusted the `html` markup. Cleanup, mostly.

```css
body {overflow-x: hidden; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.OpenContainer {
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.ImageContainer {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 960px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;
}

.ImageInfo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 250px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
    flex: 0 0 250px;
    background-color:#bfc0c4;
    padding:10px;
}
.ImageInfo h2 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.md-social {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
.md-social>a,.sm-social>a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ImageBuy {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 62px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 62px;
    flex: 0 0 62px;
    background-color:#e5e8ed;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sm-social img, .md-social img {
    width: 39px;
    height: 36px;
}
input[type=image] {
    display: inline-block;
}
.sm-social {
    display: none;
}
.exit {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    color:black;
    z-index:1;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .ImageContainer {
        max-width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .ImageContainer {
        max-width: inherit;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .ImageInfo {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
            -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
                flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    .ImageBuy {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
            -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
                flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
    .md-social {
        display: none;
    }
    .sm-social {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .ImageBuy {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .ImageBuy>*:last-child {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 80px;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 80px;
        flex: 0 0 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="OpenContainer">
  <a class="exit" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
  <div class="ImageContainer">
    <div class="ImageBig">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fWtWeUr.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="ImageInfo">
      <h2>Amsterdam</h2>
      <p>Carré Theatre alongside the busy Amstel river.</p>
      <div class="md-social">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qyrEwYp.png" />
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FFPzxIb.png" />
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qyrEwYp.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <p>Keywords: #Carre, #Amsterdam, #Locks, #AmstelRiver</div>
    <div class="ImageBuy">
      <div class="sm-social">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qyrEwYp.png" />
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FFPzxIb.png" />
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qyrEwYp.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/FLdR6hX.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <div>ams1</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I also fixed the desktop view (it had a real problem when page height was smaller than image height).

You don't owe me anything. First one's on the house.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Andrei! Appreciate it! but why 2 times Social Media ? :(

Comment: Because you need them in two different positions in DOM to be displayed as you specified. If they must be unique, they can be moved on the fly with JavaScript, on resize event.